# Postgres 9.2 INSERT skipping duplicates from string with separated values

Tags: postgresql-9.2

Postgres version 9.2

How to INSERT data into table (table has single column "name") non duplicate values, with just one query.
Without Postgres error on duplicate insert.

For example table has two rows with values:

```
AAA, BBB
```

I have data string comma separated values:

```
'AAA,BBB,CCC'
```

I want to create INSERT query after which execution data in table would be tree rows:

```
AAA, BBB, CCC
```

Postgres 9.5 has nice INSERT parameter "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING", but my postgres version does not support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution with single query:

```
INSERT INTO table (name)
  SELECT * FROM unnest(string_to_array('AAA,BBB,CCC', ',')) col 
    WHERE col NOT IN (SELECT name FROM table);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `NOT EXISTS` construct:

```
db=# create table t(i int primary key);
CREATE TABLE
db=# with d(v) as (values(1),(2),(3))
insert into t select v from d;
INSERT 0 3
db=# with d(v) as (values(1),(2),(3),(4))
insert into t select v from d where not exists (select 1 from t where i =v);
INSERT 0 1
```

or use plpgsql with `exception` handling (for atomicy)